# Explaining base peak for but-3-en-1-ol mass spectrum?

Tags: organic-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

The mass spectrum for but-3-en-1-ol shows 42 as the base peak, but I don't know how this fragment ion is generated.

I would expect the most favorable fragmentation to occur between C1 and C2, but neither the allylic nor the hydroxymethyl fragments would have a mass of 42.

Comment: I suspect that thermal electrocyclic fragmentation occurs where the OH hydrogen is transfered to C4 and formaldehyde and propene are formed. m/z=42 is the molecular ion of propene, C3H6. See: https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/direct_frame_top.cgi

Comment: Either this or the other option could be standard alpha cleavage leading to an intermediate [CH2OH+, allyl radical] ion-molecule complex, followed by a proton transfer (as PA of formaldehyde 712kJ/mol is lower than that of the allyl radical 736kJ/mol). This would mean the same bond cleavage could lead to both the m/z 31 (direct complex dissociation) and m/z 42 (proton transfer in the ion-molecule intermediate) most abundant fragments. Definite answer would require ab initio (and probably RRKM) modelling.